# Using distinct and max to get the maximum value for a unique string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in SQL:

```
column_1     column_2  
-------      -------
string_a      5   
string_b      1     
string_c      2
string_a      4        
string_b      3    
string_c      6
```

I am working to use DISTINCT and MAX so the outcome is that for a unique string in column_1 to obtain the maximum value in column_2. The result should be as follows:

```
column_1     column_2
string_a      5
string_b      3
string_c      6
```

I am fairly new with SQL and I haven't found a query that would help me with this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a straightforward aggregation - group by on `column_1` and use `max` on `column_2`. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

A simple aggregation should do the trick.

```
Select column_1
      ,max(column_2) as column_2
 From  YourTable
 Group By column_1
```